# Subtracting binaries using two's complement

Tags: computer-architecture, binary-arithmetic

I am trying to subtract these two binary numbers:

$  1110
- 1011$

First I convert 1011 to two's complement by doing 1011 to 0100 and then adding 1 to get 0101. Then I add the first number to the converted two's complement number:

$1110$

$+$ $0101$

$-----$

$0011$

0 + 1 = 1

1 + 0 = 1

1 + 1 = 0 carry 1

carry 1 + 1 + 0 = 0

For a final answer of $0011$ which is 3 in decimal, however, the answer in my book says it should be 2 or 0010...?

Comment: what is your book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your book is wrong and what you are doing is correct.

1110 is 14 in decimal and 1011 is 11 in decimal. Hence the answer should be 3 i.e. 0011